# 'StructType' object has no attribute 'toDDL'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running this script with spark 2.4.3 & python 3.6.10

```py
columns = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df = rdd.toDF()
print(df.schema.toDDL)
```

> AttributeError: 'StructType' object has no attribute 'toDDL'

[The java documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html#toDDL--) mentions that `toDDL` function is available from spark 2.4.0, which is not in [the python documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.types).

Is there any other way to use this java function from python?

Comment: `toDLL` is clearly not available.  The function you're asking about is `toDDL`.

Comment: The document you mentioned is Java document, while you're using PySpark wrapper and it's clearly [not available](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType), even in [the source code](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#StructType). If you really want to use that Java function, you need to access via `sc._jvm`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call the `toDDL` method on the Java dataframe object:

```
df._jdf.schema().toDDL()
```